# PHP: value not being passed through URL

Tags: php, javascript

i'm a beginner at web development, so i'm having a hard time on this problem,i'm trying to make a website that gets stats from any player from a game that i play, it works by typing the player's name on the textbox then when you click on 'ok' it calls a js function that calls a php function that gets the xml on the game website api then print the results , when using my local server (apache) everything runs smoothly, no errors, but when i upload the files to my host the variable is not being passed, and i'm not sure why, here's the url to my web site www.statsofnewerth.sevencut.com.br/playerStats.php, just type my username in the box "Alcartur", then it should return one of my stats, but it's just blank, i put an alert to show the nick variable and the value returned, here's the code :

playerStats.php

```
<div class="search-panel">
<label>Search for player:</label>   
 <input name="playerName" id="txt_playerName" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
 <input name="btnPlayerSearch" type="button" value="Ok" onclick="requestPlayerData()" />
 </div>
```

form.js

```
    function requestPlayerData(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "src/wait.gif";
    document.getElementById('wait-panel').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('wait-panel').appendChild(img);
    var nickname = document.getElementById('txt_playerName').value;
    ajaxFunction(nickname);
  }

  function ajaxFunction(nickname){  
    $('#wait-panel').load("httpRequest.php?nickname="+nickname, function(html){
  alert(html);
});
}
```

and httpRequest.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
$q = $_GET['nickname'];
echo 'nickname'.$q;
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.heroesofnewerth.com/xml_requester.php?f=player_stats&opt=nick&nick[]='.$q);
$result = $sxe->xpath("//*[@name='rnk_amm_team_rating']");
print_r($result);
?>
```

just remembering that in my local server it works.

Sry for any english mistakes, it's not my first language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the alert comes up as blank, or not at all? Do you have a base tag set that is pointing to your local server still? I had that problem today with an ajax call!

Comment: It's coming blank, with only the hard coded strings and no, no base tags.

Answer (score 1):

is data loaded at all?

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.heroesofnewerth.com/xml_requester.php?f=player_stats&opt=nick&nick[]='.$q);
var_dump($sxe);die();
```

Comment: Yes, since the variable nickname is blank, the request is returning with an error, this error is returned when there's some invalid character. "object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> string(39) "A problem occurred formatting accounts." }"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your httpRequest page is returning the correct data.  I don't think it is.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
$q = $_GET['nickname'];
echo 'nickname'.$q;
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.heroesofnewerth.com/xml_requester.php?f=player_stats&opt=nick&nick[]='.$q);
$result = $sxe->xpath("//*[@name='rnk_amm_team_rating']");
//print_r($result); // I don't think this can work?  could be wrong

echo $result[0]; // this returns the first xpath match and outputs the value of the node, which is the "rnk_amm_team_rating" thing

// since this php says it returns XML (the header line), it should either do so or get rid of the header.
?>
```

Comment: print_r($result); is working, it prints the entire array in a readable way, like i said, this is running perfectly in my localhost server, it's just not working on the remote server(hostgator), and it's not returning the right data on the remote because echo 'nickname'.$q; is showing that it's blank, so the http://xml.heroesofnewerth.com/xml_requester.php?f=player_stats&opt=nick&nick[]='.$q url is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found out the solution, even though i was putting the files on the remote server i think when i acessed the site it was using some old file from some cache in my computer(does it even make sense?), or it was some problem with the host, i don't really know, but now i did a refresh on the wesite and it was working normaly, if anyone have any idea of what might have happened i would like to hear. Thanks problem solved.